# Icon badge and remote notifications in center

Tags: iphone, objective-c, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I have problem with application icon badge and remote notifications. When i receive remote notification iOS set correctly badge value. If i launch application directly from remote notification (stored in notifications center), application will set badge to value 0 (to clear icon badge). After this procedure, system clear all notifications in center, so my question is how store notification in center even when i set badge value equal to 0? I want clear notifications stored in center only by clear button.

All advises are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can't, resetting the badge number will remove all notification from the notification center.

Facebook will do this, after you opened the app it reset the badge and ask the server for the data. All other notification are now removed and facebook implemented there own logic in the app to see the notifications.